# Firebase image upload is not working i don't have any error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create app with react and I want to upload multiple image in firebase storage everything is going fine but my image are not uploading i can't figure out why below is my code for upload form

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import {
  getStorage,
  ref,
  uploadBytesResumable,
  getDownloadURL,
} from "firebase/storage";
import { firebaseApp } from "../../../firebase.config";

export default function UploadForm() {

  const [imageAsset, setImageAsset] = useState([]);
  const [urls, setUrls] = useState([]);

  const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp); // Firebase Storage
  const firebaseDb = getFirestore(firebaseApp); // Firebase FireStore

  function UploadImage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);

    for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
      const Images = e.target.files[i];
      Images["id"] = Math.random();
      setImageAsset((prevState) => [...prevState, Images]);
    }

    const promises = [];

    imageAsset.map((image) => {
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `Images/${Date.now()}-${image.name}}`);
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, image);
      promises.push(uploadTask);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapShot) => {
          const uploadProgress =
            (snapShot.bytesTransferred / snapShot.totalBytes) * 100;
          setProgress(uploadProgress);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        async () => {
          await storage
            .ref("Images")
            .child(image.name)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then((urls) => {
              setUrls((prevState) => [...prevState, urls]);
              setLoading(false);
            });
        }
      );
      Promise.all(promises)
        .then(() => alert("done"))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {}, [title, description, imageAsset]);

  return (
          <input type={"file"} multiple onChange={UploadImage} />
  );
}
```

In console it shows 1 as a progress even i didn't select any image i don't understand why? it was perfectly working before when i was uploading single image.

Comment: Could you create a [creating a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I tried to create simple sample tell me if it works